# Scrolling data in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm working on a small text editor in ncurses with the purpose of learning more about the library. One of the first challenges was implementing a proper scrollable text buffer, retaining the editing abilities. I've created a cursor struct, containing the screen coordinates and the buffer coordinates. When you move the cursor, the x and y are constrained to the LINES and COLS max values. The buffer coordinates, however, are constrainted to the limits of the text file (size and linesize).

This works well, but i was wondering if there's a better way of doing this. Right now, every cursor movement operation results in modifications to both coordinate systems. Maybe there's a way of converting between coordinates and keep just one (the buffer one, preferably)?

Comment: I don't see how you can have a single coordinate record to take care of both the text and the display, which don't share any sizes. I recommend separating *form* from *function*. The *function* is the detail of the text file, its *form* is what you see.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a pad? As a window can be no larger than the terminal itself, else data is lost when if passes over the edge boundary. A pad is used to allow for larger data display by the use of **`newpad`**. The pad can be any length the system memory has available; viewed by way of a window **`subpad`** which displays the contents of the pad at a specified location.